# A Kazhdan-Warner type problem

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, differential-equations

Let $X$ be a compact Riemannian manifold and I am interested in the following set of equations:
\begin{align*}
\Delta f+u\cdot e^{f+\lambda}=c\\
\lambda-2f=g
\end{align*}
where $u,g$ are given real valued functions on $X$. $u>0$ and $c$ is a constant. We need to solve for $f$ and $\lambda$. Notice that for a fixed $\lambda$ the first equation always has a solution if $c>0$. So, we can put that in our assumption as well. Is there any conditions which assures solutions to these set of equations? If yes then is it unique? Any source, comment or ideas are welcome.

Comment: Is something missing from your equations? If $g$ is given, when don't just just rewrite the first equation as $\Delta f + u \cdot e^g \cdot e^{3f}= c$? If you absorb $e^g$ into $u$ and rescale, shouldn't you just get back to the question that you know how to solve?

Comment: @WillieWong Thanks, I had a wrong impression that it had to be $e^f$ only and not $e^{kf}$ for any $k\in\mathbb{Z}^+$. If $u<0$ and $c<0$, then do we have a solution similarly? I mean is there a similar version for that case as well?